# Show form fields successively. (Javascript/CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

does anyone know how to show form fields successively like on https://www.hioscar.com/get-oscar/2016/quote/? It looks like Javascript, but I can't find the code. Should be animated and should show the next field without hitting return. Is there a framework for this?

kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using jquery. Here is a basic example :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#input1').on('keyup',function(){
   if ($('#input1').val().length === 5) {
     $('#input2').show();
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input id="input1">
</div>
<div>
<input id="input2" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

In this example, the form opened showing only one field.

On key up, we check if the length of the value of the field is equal to 5.

If it is, we show the second field.

Comment: That's what I looked for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create you form and show only the first input (using css). After every input field is filled (that can be done in many ways, such as by creating an onclick or onblur events). After that you can show the next input field changing the css.

A good approach would be having 'steps' set as ids os classes on your form fields so your function that will show/hide the fields will receive it as parameter to act properly.